# Accessing Visible UICollectionReusableViews When Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to modify a `UICollectionView` using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to support some parallax effects when scrolling. I am able to do this on the `UICollectionViewCells` by implementing something like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)mainScrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = [mainScrollView contentOffset];
    for (UIView *cell in [self.mainCollectionView visibleCells])
        if ([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(KSParallaxCell)])
            [((UIView <GSParallaxCell> *)cell) parallaxInScrollView:mainScrollView toX:offset.x toY:offset.y];
}
```

Is it possible to iterate over the supplementary views (`UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` and `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`) to check if they support the same parallax delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to check obvious of looping through subviews instead of calling the visible cells:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)mainScrollView 
{
     CGPoint offset = [mainScrollView contentOffset];
     for (UIView *cell in self.mainCollectionView.subviews)
       if ([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(KSParallaxCell)])
         [((UIView <GSParallaxCell> *)cell) parallaxInScrollView:mainScrollView toX:offset.x toY:offset.y]; 
}
```